# How to return field based on other fields with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose schema that looks something like this:

```
{
    _id: someId,
    name: 'mike',
    keys: {
        apiKey: 'fsddsfdsfdsffds',
        secretKey: 'sddfsfdsfdsfdsds'
    }
}
```

I don't want to send back to the front the keys of course, but I want some indication, like:

```
{
    _id: someId,
    name: 'mike',
    hasKeys: true
}
```

There is built in way to create 'field' on the way based on other fields, or do I need every time fetch the whole document, check if keys is not empty and set object property based on that?

Comment: Can you show the code for your schema & model as well as how you send the data to the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mongo version 4.2+ What you're looking for is called [pipelined updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), it let's you use a (restricted) aggregate pipeline as your update allowing the usage of existing field values.

Here is a toy example with your data:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
{ _id: someId },
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "hasKeys": {
        $cond: [
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$keys",
              false
            ]
          },
          true,
          false
        ]
      }
    }
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oh8ZMMREYPa)
For older Mongo versions you have to do it in code.

If you don't want to update the actual document but just populate this field when you fetch it you can use the same aggregation to fetch the document

Answer (score 0):

you can use $project in mongoose aggregation like this.

```
$project: { hasKeys: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$keys', null] }, false, true]}}
```